# Web scraping: How to match search engine results with dataset values in R?

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to match my dataset with search engine results from the following link: ftp://ftp.uspto.gov/pub/patdata/

What I want to do is:

1. Figure out how to look up each value in my dataset in the search engine
2. Generate the total number of search results associated with whatever value I enter into the website's 'Term 1' field (from my dataset values), only filtering for 'Assignee Name' in the website's 'Field 1' field

The furthest I've gotten with my code so far is:

```
library(RSelenium)
remDr = remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html")
```

Comment: Your code is to turn on chrome browser.

Comment: I can't access your site. But your problem seems to be easily solved in the tutorial. It's hard to scrap the data on the site by changing it. Find out how to scrap and change the data. I think looking for it in person will help you better.